# No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, passwords

I have created a hash for password protected PDF with John The Ripper which looks like:
`Protected.pdf:$pdf$2*3*128*-3904*1*16*fa8b5911e99eb1a6d74b033402dce8d0*:::::../../Protected.pdf`

and it is saved in key.hash file in root folder. When I run the command `john ../../key.hash` it returns error
`No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)`
I'm using John The Ripper [john-1.8.0-jumbo-1], in ubuntu

Comment: Where are you running the command, give the output of `pwd` please - `../../` means 2 directories above where you're running it from, is this actually what you want, or did you just copy this from somewhere?

Comment: yes, I'm well aware of that. My `key.hash` file is located in `/root/key.hash` and the tool is located in `/root/john-1.8.0-jumbo-1/run`

Comment: does it still not work if you use the absolute path?

Comment: Yes, it is still not working. I tried by moving `key.hash` file to /root/john-1.8.0-jumbo-1/run` directory also.

Comment: ok how exactly did you create this hash.

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the format using the option `--format=pdf`
example:

```
sudo john --format=pdf hashfile.txt
```

where `hashfile.txt` must contain the hash generated by `pdf2john`

Comment: How? Where? This may be helpful information, but without context and explanation it is just a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: @music2myear This is a clear answer.

Comment: @DimiDak it wasn't when I made that comment. The comment was a single line, the first line, without the "... example:" bit or following. The author edited the answer the next day adding the rest of the information making it the clear answer you see now.